# Using JavaScript, why is my onmouseover event not being fired?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am writing a JavaScript library for a school project that will allow you to implement drag and drop.  I have implemented dragging.  When the user drags a draggable object, I create a partially transparent clone of the object that follows their mouse pointer until they lift up on the mouse (`onmouseup`).  When they are dragging over a droppable object, I want there to be a visual to show the user that they can drop their object there.
jQuery UI has accomplished this:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#visual-feedback

I can not get this to work because my `onmouseover` event is not being fired because my clone element is in the way.  My clone always follows the mouse pointer.  How can I get the event to fire to the element under the clone?

Comment: make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onMouseDown/Up` are defined on the elements you are dragging. Elements beneath the dragged object will not be able to catch `onMouseOver` event. Why? Because you are dragging object and that object only can catch the `onMouseOver` event.

So, to detect destination, maybe you should create a script that calculates the coordinates of the droppable object and store them. Then search if the mouse coordinates are inside the `droppableObjectCoordinates` and after left mouse button is released, drop what you dragged to the correct position.

Answer (score 0):

Use a mousemove event on the body that checks the mouse coordinates against the object clientX and clientY.